# Overload constructors for a class structure with more than one instance of that class structure

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor, overloading

Hello to all that read

I am self learning C++ from a text book.

...and I have been given a serious of questions that I am have trouble interpreting, the questions are:

**4.
Modify the constructor of Exercise 3 so that it assigns a new ID number as each variable is established. The ID number should be output to the screen.**

**Please Note: Exercise 3 was just adding a Class constructor to the class structure - and basically setting all the class private member variables to '0' within that added constructor.

**5.
Add constructors to the class of exercise 4. They should output the ID number when they are invoked.**

**6.
Write a constructor whose argument is an ID number. Overload it with the constructor of(Exercise 5) and then Write a main program to test this new constructor.**

**So the questions: 4 and 5 are confusing me as they appear to be asking the same questions (i.e outputting the I.D numbers) and I need more than one 'constructor' in order to do this( I get that part).

**Question 6 Is effectively asking me to overload more than one instance declared of the class with an ID number as the argument!!!! I am confused because in my text book it specifically states that you cannot have an argument for a constructor when you have an array of classes declared within in the main program.

So if anyone can shed light on these questions and clarify how they would proceed I would appreciate the help. I appreciate that I may of interpreted the questions wrongly that is why I am asking for help.

**Please note: The name of the class: 'class classroom' is not ideal but it is what I copied from the text book question!

**Please also note that I have answered (I think!) exercise/question 4 by adding code that Id's each instance of the class variable.

And the relevant code relating to the above questions are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;


  class classroom{

         char name[25];
         int student_id;
         float grades[10];
         float average;
         int num_tests;
         float letter_grade;
         **static int next_student_id;**
  public:       
         void enter_name_id(void);
         void enter_grade(void);
         void average_grades(void);
         void letter_grades(void);
         void output_name_id_grade(void);
         classroom();

  };

         **int classroom::next_student_id=1;**
```

and the constructor:

```
classroom::classroom(){

          int i;

          num_tests=0;

         **student_id=next_student_id++;**           

         **cout<<"\nstudent id: "<<student_id;**

          average=0.0;
          for(i=0;i<10;i++){

            grades[i]=0.0;

          }

          for(i=0;i<27;i++){

             name[i]='-';       
          }
          cout<<"\n*****************Finished*****************";
     }
```

And the main program declaration:

```
int main()
{       
      classroom students[3];
//and so on...
}
```

and the code added for  question/Exercise 4 was:

in the class structure I added the following private member variable:

> ```
> **static int next_student_id;**
> ```

and outside of the class structure I initialized the static variable to 1

> **int classroom::next_student_id=1;**

and in the constructor I added this code: which basically outputted to the screen a unique ID for each instance of classroom class variable:

> **student_id=next_student_id++;**
>
> ** cout<<"\nstudent id: "<

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions 4 and 5 do appear to be the same from what you've provided - I'd reread it carefully to be sure, but it wouldn't be the first time textbook examples had a typo (in fact, I've run across that many times - alot of book companies are lazy when it comes to the exercises).

You do have the right answer with your static counter, so I wouldn't worry about it - you've understood the goal and solved the problem.

Question 6... it sounds like it wants you to just add an extra constructor to the class - so, you would have the default constructor (which you must explicitly write, but you already have done this in order to do your static counter), and you would also have a one-parameter constructor taking an integer.  The one-parameter constructor should not need to use the static variable as it is allowing the user to provide the id to the class explicitly.

Moving on (since I think you've already got all of this), you are also correct in thinking that you can't provide an argument to a constructor when making an array.  To test #6 as it suggests, you'll either have to make a stand-alone object (i.e. not an array), or something like a std::vector or other container that provides this capability.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
    public:
        A(int i) { /* Empty */ }
}; 

int main()
{
    //Creates a new vector holding 5 A's initialized with the 2nd parameter.
    std::vector<A> myVec(5, A(7));
}
```

Note that this technically creates a temporary A which is used to initialize the 5 vector entries.  Also note that a std::vector is part of the STL (standard library), and it is basically a dynamically sized array.

Comment: You can also have a useful tick for helping

Answer (score 1):

Where, point 6, requires to have an array of class objects?

```
int main()
{       
  classroom studentA(100);
  classroom studentB();
  classroom studentC(200);
  classroom studentD();
  classroom students[100];
  //and so on...
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks neagoegab, I can see your answer would be the way to proceed and answer my question 6. I will investigate and come back, in the mean time you can also have a 'useful tick, from me for helping.